# Python library or tool to get bounding boxes in a searchable/selectable PDF, without using tesseract or any other OCR related solution

Tags: python, pdf, computer-vision, ocr, bounding-box

I am unable to find a python script or library or a tool which can give me bounding boxes around the texts in a searchable/selectable  PDF. All of the tools I found first convert the PDF to an image, either using GhostScript or some other tool, and then extract the bounding boxes using an OCR solution like Tesseract. But is there any pure python based solution which extracts the bounding boxes around the texts in a searchable/selectable PDF.

I tried finding solutions, and found some, but they use an OCR service like Tesseract at some point.
The following are some of the solutions that I found.

- https://updf.com/convert-pdf/convert-pdf-to-xml/
- https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html
- https://towardsdatascience.com/build-an-image-pdf-text-extraction-tool-with-tesseract-ocr-using-client-side-javascript-6126031001

Comment: Some of the solutions I found are in Java, like https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.7/javadocs/org/apache/fontbox/util/BoundingBox.html, but I am looking for python based solutions.

Comment: One solution in python is pdftotext, but unfortunately it is not getting installed due to an issue with my system.

Comment: My OS is Windows, and the error says poppler (a C library which does the actual work) could not be found by MS Visual Studio Build tools, and I have tried all the solutions suggested by those who are facing the same issue, but with no success, thus I am looking for other python based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When text is written inside a pdf by whatever means it has no boundary or box (can even be outside page related boxes) simply a design height and position:-

```
{
        "text": {
            "text": "Hello World!",
            "points": 96 ,
            "x": 36 ,
            "y": 684
        }
    }
```

internally in a PDF that will look like this (note 96 is points and the xy is applied as a matrix)

```
stream
q
BT
/ 96 Tf
1 0 0 1 36 684 Tm
(Hello World!) Tj
ET
Q

endstream
```

So, to extract its self-imposed boundary, we need tools that return the font metrics tallied into overall height and length(s). Many python and command line tools can provide their own interpretation of what that may be.

You suggest that many python utilities depend on poppler for text manipulation and that  can return the metrics in many ways. however -bbox-layout as html may not be as expected

[image]

Far better for xy extraction is mutool convert we can see as HTML it retained 96 as the height (however as html the co-ords are not pdf co-ords)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{background-color:slategray}
div{position:relative;background-color:white;margin:1em auto;box-shadow:1px 1px 8px -2px black}
p{position:absolute;white-space:pre;margin:0}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page1" style="width:595.0pt;height:792.0pt">
<p style="top:31.2pt;left:36.0pt;line-height:96.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:96.0pt">Hello World!</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Better yet we can ask for text structure
`mutool convert -F stext -o hello.txt hello.pdf`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
<page id="page1" width="595" height="792">
<block bbox="36 4.7999956 558.7201 136.704">
<line bbox="36 4.7999956 558.7201 136.704" wmode="0" dir="1 0">
<font name="Helvetica" size="96">
<char quad="36 4.7999956 105.312 4.7999956 36 136.704 105.312 136.704" x="36" y="108" color="#000000" c="H"/>
<char quad="105.312007 4.7999956 158.688 4.7999956 105.312007 136.704 158.688 136.704" x="105.312007" y="108" color="#000000" c="e"/>
<char quad="158.68802 4.7999956 180.00002 4.7999956 158.68802 136.704 180.00002 136.704" x="158.68802" y="108" color="#000000" c="l"/>
<char quad="180.00002 4.7999956 201.31201 4.7999956 180.00002 136.704 201.31201 136.704" x="180.00002" y="108" color="#000000" c="l"/>
<char quad="201.31201 4.7999956 254.68802 4.7999956 201.31201 136.704 254.68802 136.704" x="201.31201" y="108" color="#000000" c="o"/>
<char quad="254.68802 4.7999956 281.376 4.7999956 254.68802 136.704 281.376 136.704" x="254.68802" y="108" color="#000000" c=" "/>
<char quad="281.37605 4.7999956 372.00004 4.7999956 281.37605 136.704 372.00004 136.704" x="281.37605" y="108" color="#000000" c="W"/>
<char quad="372.00007 4.7999956 425.37608 4.7999956 372.00007 136.704 425.37608 136.704" x="372.00007" y="108" color="#000000" c="o"/>
<char quad="425.37608 4.7999956 457.34407 4.7999956 425.37608 136.704 457.34407 136.704" x="425.37608" y="108" color="#000000" c="r"/>
<char quad="457.34407 4.7999956 478.65608 4.7999956 457.34407 136.704 478.65608 136.704" x="457.34407" y="108" color="#000000" c="l"/>
<char quad="478.65608 4.7999956 532.03207 4.7999956 478.65608 136.704 532.03207 136.704" x="478.65608" y="108" color="#000000" c="d"/>
<char quad="532.0321 4.7999956 558.7201 4.7999956 532.0321 136.704 558.7201 136.704" x="532.0321" y="108" color="#000000" c="!"/>
</font>
</line>
</page>
</document>
```

or run a trace to see how much each letter advances

```
<document filename="hello.pdf">
<page number="1" mediabox="0 0 595 792">
<set_default_colorspaces gray="DeviceGray" rgb="DeviceRGB" cmyk="DeviceCMYK" oi="None"/>
<group bbox="0 0 595 792" isolated="1" knockout="0" blendmode="Normal" alpha="1">
    <fill_text colorspace="DeviceGray" color="0" ri="1" bp="1" op="0" opm="0" transform="1 0 0 -1 0 792">
        <span font="Helvetica" wmode="0" bidi="0" trm="96 0 0 96">
            <g unicode="H" glyph="H" x="36" y="684" adv=".722"/>
            <g unicode="e" glyph="e" x="105.312007" y="684" adv=".556"/>
            <g unicode="l" glyph="l" x="158.68802" y="684" adv=".222"/>
            <g unicode="l" glyph="l" x="180.00002" y="684" adv=".222"/>
            <g unicode="o" glyph="o" x="201.31201" y="684" adv=".556"/>
            <g unicode=" " glyph="space" x="254.68802" y="684" adv=".278"/>
            <g unicode="W" glyph="W" x="281.37605" y="684" adv=".944"/>
            <g unicode="o" glyph="o" x="372.00007" y="684" adv=".556"/>
            <g unicode="r" glyph="r" x="425.37608" y="684" adv=".333"/>
            <g unicode="l" glyph="l" x="457.34407" y="684" adv=".222"/>
            <g unicode="d" glyph="d" x="478.65608" y="684" adv=".556"/>
            <g unicode="!" glyph="exclam" x="532.0321" y="684" adv=".278"/>
        </span>
    </fill_text>
</group>
</page>
</document>
```

So every tool has its own way of describing 96pt text starting at 36,684 that is roughly 523x96pts

If you want simple textruns in different output from one commercial tool

`pdf2text --output_bbox -f textruns hello.pdf>text`

```
36, 664.128, 522.72, 88.8, "Helvetica", , 12, "Hello World!"
```

NOTE undersized above as plain text or oversized below as xml !!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page num="1" crop_box="0, 0, 595, 792" media_box="0, 0, 595, 792" rotate="0">
<Flow id="1">
<Para id="0">
<Line box="36, 662.4, 522.72, 110.976">
Hello World!</Line>
</Para>
</Flow>
</Page>
```

And another $79.95 commercial tool will yield

```
[Page #1] *** initial words ***
    word: x=36.00..254.69 y=39.07..127.87 base=108.00 fontSize=96.00 rot=0 link=00000000 'Hello'
    word: x=281.38..558.72 y=39.07..127.87 base=108.00 fontSize=96.00 rot=0 link=00000000 '!World'

[Page #1] *** flows ***

flow: x=36.00..558.72 y=39.07..127.87 pri:36.00..558.72
  block: rot=0 x=36.00..558.72 y=39.07..127.87 pri=36.00..558.72
    line:
      word: x=36.00..254.69 y=39.07..127.87 base=108.00 fontSize=96.00 space=1: 'Hello'
      word: x=281.38..558.72 y=39.07..127.87 base=108.00 fontSize=96.00 space=0: 'World!'
  
[Page #1] *** line fragments ***
line: x=36.00..558.72 y=39.07..127.87 base=108.00 'Hello World!'
```

Thus no consistent way to define a box but mutool is most reliable.